# The parser in json.Decode not works, return a list instead of a Map [Dart, Flutter]

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I've got an issue when I'm reading a Json file from a url. The json.decode returns to me a list, whose I can't convert to a Map. I don't want to do a "split" the string and make a lot of miraculous parsers on that. My idea is to use the Map, as expected. 
My JSON file (config_app.json stored on server):

```
[
    {
    'data': '13/03/2021',
    'licao': 'Aula Inaugural',
    'info': 'blabla blabla blabla'
  },
  {
    'data': '13/03/2021',
    'licao': 'alguma coisa',
    'info': 'blabla blabla blabla'
  },
]
```

The source code:

```
Future<Map> fetchJsonDemoData() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get( 
  Uri.encodeFull('http://<url>/config_app.json'));
  print(response.body);
  List<dynamic> test = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
  print("Test: " + test[0].toString());
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

The line print(response.body); returns:

```
[
        {
        'data': '13/03/2021',
        'licao': 'Aula Inaugural',
        'info': 'blabla blabla blabla'
      },
      {
        'data': '13/03/2021',
        'licao': 'alguma coisa',
        'info': 'blabla blabla blabla'
      },
    ]
```

The line print("Test: " + test[0].toString()); returns:

```
Test: {data: 13/03/2027, licao: Aula Inaugural, info: blabla blabla blabla}
```

When I try to do that,

```
var data = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
print(data['data']);
```

I received the following error message:

> Error:type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map' in type cast

In another way when I try to do that:

```
List<dynamic> test = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
  print("Test: " + test[0].toString());
  Map valueMap = json.decode(test[0].toString());
  print(valueMap["data"].toString());
```

The answer is:

> Test: {data: 13/03/2027, licao: Aula Inaugural, info: blabla blabla
>
> blabla} Error:FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
>
> {data: 13/03/2027, licao: Aula Inaugural, info: blabla blabla blabla}
>
> ^

I tried in different ways to parse my Json in a Map, but I failed in all points. I've got the simple idea to receive the answer from the server and put it in a Map to transfer in a Future, to use the snapshot.data["key"]. However, it is not working for me, and I just tried a lot of source code examples from the internet...

Comment: Your JSON contains list of maps.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I don't believe in that, I lost hours in this simple point - vision blind.
Thanks, you solved my problem. In this way, Map valueMap = test[0];
  print(valueMap["data"]); I get the correct value using a key.